# How to use previous regex definition in another definition in Flex?

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

Suppose I have keyword definitions (case insensitive):

```
CLASS    (c|C)(l|L)(a|A)(s|S){2}
IF       (i|I)(f|F)
...more....
```

Now I want to define a `KEYWORD` which consists of all the keywords:

```
KEYWORD   (CLASS|IF| ....more....)
IDENTIFIER     [^KEYWORD][a-zA-Z0-9]
```

However, doing this way, it will only treat `CLASS` as a string and is not substituted with previous definition. Furthermore,I want to use the `KEYWORD` definition in `IDENTIFIER`, is it valid (let's assume `KEYWORD` is substituted)?

Comment: I removed the Adobe Flex tag and replaced it w/ Gnu-Flex; as I think that is more appropriate for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found out how to use the previous definition here: http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/flex_6.html#SEC6

We must add {} around the previous definitions:

```
KEYWORD   ({CLASS}|{IF}| ....more....)
IDENTIFIER     [^{KEYWORD}][a-zA-Z0-9]
```

I answer myself for future reference from others.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, too. That even gets you a badge!